# Finding even numbers in an array

Tags: algorithm, function

> Given an array of length n containing at most e even numbers and a
>   function isEven that returns true if the input is even and false
>   otherwise, write a function that prints all the even numbers in the
>   array using the fewest number of calls to isEven.

The only thing I could think was to do a linear search and stop after I hit the end of the array or found e even numbers. Can someone please tell me a better way?

Comment: What have you done already, or did you expect us to do it all for you?

Comment: I updated my question. THe best I could think to do was a linear search. Can you please tell me if there's a better way?

Comment: can we use bitwise and? if(!(arr[i] & 1)) print arr[i] -- i'll troll along now.

Comment: @AmirAfghani, Or use `!IsOdd(int)`. :D

Comment: Why not just print all the numbers in the array? The question doesn't say you can't and it satisfies the answer without ever calling isEven() :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do a binary search instead. Write a function that does the following:

- Start with `A = array` and `n = length(A)`.
- While `n>1`

  - Set `L = [A[0],A[1],...,A[k-1]]` and `R = [A[k],A[k+1],...,A[n-1]]` where `k = floor(n/2)`
  - If `isEven(product of elements of L)`, then set `A=L` and `n = k`,
  - Otherwise set `A=R` and `n = n-k`.
- If `isEven(A[0])`, return `A[0]`,
- Otherwise, return `-1`.

Run a `for` loop that will have at most `e` iterations. Each time run the algorithm above to find an even number, if the output is `-1` stop, there are no more to find. Otherwise, print the output, remove it from the array, and iterate for at most `e` trials.

The binary search algorithm takes `log(n)` calls to `isEven`, and you must run it at most `e` times, so there are a total of `e log(n)` calls to `isEven`.

Therefore you want to take this approach whenever `e log(n) < n`, otherwise use the linear search, which takes `n` calls to `isEven`.

Comment: Doesn't that require the array to be sorted?

Comment: @VargaPéter How so? You're testing whether there is an even number among the chosen half. That's all.

Comment: +1, Tricky, tricky. This will get you a better grade than my practical answer of "memory is cheap, memoize."

Comment: @PengOne I get that e log(n) is going to be faster than linear, but surely creating the product of elements of L is going to be a linear operation which rather defeats the whole binary search approach. I just can't see how iteratively calling this function would be faster than a simple linear approach.

Comment: @RobinWelch The only thing I am optimizing for is "_using the fewest number of calls to isEven_". I don't claim this is better in any other sense.

Comment: @PengOne A very fair point - (Mental note to self to read the requirements more carefully and not make up ones of my own!) :)

Comment: Why should all of the even numbers be on one side of the pivot?  It seems you must test both branches, and descend into each on a match.

Comment: @phs It's not the case that they will all be on one side of the pivot. However, if there is an even number, this algorithm will find it and that number will be removed from the input array on subsequent iterations. The algorithm terminates after `e` steps (having found `e` even numbers) or when the return is `-1` indicating that there are no more even numbers to be found.

Comment: @PengOne Ah, I didn't see the outer loop in the paragraph below.