# Finding even numbers in an array without using feedback

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I saw this post: [Finding even numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582959/finding-even-numbers-in-an-array/8584598) and I was thinking about how you could do it without feedback. Here's what I mean.

> Given an array of length n containing at most `e` even numbers and a
>   function `isEven` that returns true if the input is even and false
>   otherwise, write a function that prints all the even numbers in the
>   array using the fewest number of calls to `isEven`.

The answer on the post was to use a binary search, which is neat since it doesn't mean the array has to be in order. The number of times you have to check if a number is even is `e log n` instead if `n` because you do a binary search (`log n`) to find one even number each time (`e` times).

But that idea means that you divide the array in half, test for evenness, then decide which half to keep based on the result.

My question is whether or not you can beat `n` calls on a fixed testing scheme where you check all the numbers you want for evenness without knowing the outcome, and then figure out where the even numbers are after you've done all the tests based on the results. So I guess it's no-feedback or blind or some term like that.

I was thinking about this for a while and couldn't come up with anything. The binary search idea doesn't work at all with this constraint, but maybe something else does? Even getting down to `n/2` calls instead of `n` (yes, I know they are the same big-O) would be good.

Comment: Could you please explain the binary search solution in more details? I somehow can't think of a way to use binary search here.

Comment: @istrandjev look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8584598/661284

Comment: The linked answer is taking advantage of a loop-hole.  It supposes that we're allowed to multiply numbers, and test the evenness of the product.  If we can use arithmetic, we can craft our own evenness test (use integer division in `2 * (x / 2) == x`) and never call `isEven` at all.

Comment: Are you also looking for a generalized version of the question (where we replace "even numbers and odd numbers" with, say, "black objects and white objects"), where `isEven` truly is a black box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to do this. I'm going to change your notation a bit.

Suppose you have `N` numbers of which at most `E` are even. Choose a sequence of distinct prime powers `q1,q2,...,qk` such that their product is at least `N^E`, i.e.

```
 qi = pi^ei
```

where `pi` is prime and `ei > 0` is an integer and

```
 q1 * q2 * ... * qk >= N^E
```

Now make a bunch of `0-1` matrices. Let `Mi` be the `qi x N` matrix where the entry in row `r` and column `c` has a `1` if `c = r mod qi` and a `0` otherwise. For example, if `qi = 3^2`, then row `2` has ones in columns `2, 11, 20, ... 2 + 9j` and `0` elsewhere.

Now stack these matrices vertically to get a `Q x N` matrix `M`, where `Q = q1 + q2 + ... + qk`. The rows of `M` tell you which numbers to multiply together (the nonzero positions). This gives a total of `Q` products that you need to test for evenness. Call each row a "trial", and say that a "trial involves `j`" if the `j`th column of that row is nonempty. The theorem you need is the following:

THEOREM: The number in position `j` is even if and only if all trials involving `j` are even.

So you do a total of `Q` trials and then look at the results. If you choose the prime powers intelligently, then `Q` should be significantly smaller than `N`. There are asymptotic results that show you can always get `Q` on the order of

```
(2E log N)^2 / 2log(2E log N)
```

This theorem is actually a corollary of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. The only place that I've seen this used is in [Combinatorial Group Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing). Apparently the problem originally arose when testing soldiers coming back from WWII for syphilis.

Comment: Thank you. This made sense after I thought about it and did an example, but I still don't know why the theorem is true.

Answer (score 7):

The technical term for "no-feedback or blind" is "non-adaptive". O(e log n) calls still suffice, but the algorithm is rather more involved.

Instead of testing the evenness of products, we're going to test the evenness of sums. Let E ≠ F be distinct subsets of {1, …, n}. If we have one array x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>n</sub> with even numbers at positions E and another array y<sub>1</sub>, …, y<sub>n</sub> with even numbers at positions F, how many subsets J of {1, …, n} satisfy

(∑<sub>i in J</sub> x<sub>i</sub>) mod 2 ≠ (∑<sub>i in J</sub> y<sub>i</sub>) mod 2?

The answer is 2<sup>n-1</sup>. Let i be an index such that x<sub>i</sub> mod 2 ≠ y<sub>i</sub> mod 2. Let S be a subset of {1, …, i - 1, i + 1, … n}. Either J = S is a solution or J = S union {i} is a solution, but not both.

For every possible outcome E, we need to make calls that eliminate every other possible outcome F. Suppose we make 2e log n calls at random. For each pair E ≠ F, the probability that we still cannot distinguish E from F is (2<sup>n-1</sup>/2<sup>n</sup>)<sup>2e log n</sup> = n<sup>-2e</sup>, because there are 2<sup>n</sup> possible calls and only 2<sup>n-1</sup> fail to distinguish. There are at most n<sup>e</sup> + 1 choices of E and thus at most (n<sup>e</sup> + 1)n<sup>e</sup>/2 pairs. By a union bound, the probability that there exists some indistinguishable pair is at most n<sup>-2e</sup>(n<sup>e</sup> + 1)n<sup>e</sup>/2 < 1 (assuming we're looking at an interesting case where e ≥ 1 and n ≥ 2), so there exists a sequence of 2e log n calls that does the job.

Note that, while I've used randomness to show that a good sequence of calls exists, the resulting algorithm is *deterministic* (and, of course, non-adaptive, because we chose that sequence without knowledge of the outcomes).

Comment: Thanks for the terminology. I'll think more about your solution and get back to you. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: I honestly didn't quite follow how to do this. Thanks for the answer. I voted for you but I'm going to accept the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is a form of [group testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing), type of a problem with the objective of reducing the cost of identifying certain elements of a set (up to **`d`** elements of a set of **`N`** elements).

As you've already stated, there are two basic principles via which the testing may be carried out:

- **Non-adaptive Group Testing**, where all the tests to be performed are decided a priori.
- **Adaptive Group Testing**, where we perform several tests, basing each test on the outcome of previous tests. Obviously, adaptive testing has a potential to reduce the cost, compared to non-adaptive testing.

Theoretical bounds for both principles have been studied, and are available [in this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing#Bounds_for_testing_on_ta.28d.2Cn.29_and_t.28d.2Cn.29), or [this paper](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/~atri/courses/coding-theory/spr10/lectures/lect11.pdf).

- For **adaptive testing**, the upper bound is **`O(d*log(N))`** (as already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584598/69809)).
- For **non-adaptive testing**, it can be shown that the upper bound is **`O(d*d/log(d)*log(N))`**, which is obviously larger than the upper bound for adaptive testing by a factor of `d/log(d)`.

This upper bound for non-adaptive testing comes from an algorithm which uses [disjunct matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_matrix): matrices of dimension `T x N` ("number of tests" x "number of elements"), where each item can be either true (if an element was included in a test), or false (if it wasn't), with a property that any subset of `d` columns must differ from all other columns by at least a single row (test inclusion). This allows linear time of decoding (there are also "d-separable" matrices where fewer test are needed, but the time complexity for their decoding is exponential and not computationaly feasible).

**Conclusion:**

> My question is whether or not you can beat `n` calls on a fixed testing scheme [...]

For such a scheme and a sufficiently large value of `N`, a disjunct matrix can be constructed which would have less than `K * [d*d/log(d)*log(N)]` rows. So, for large values of `N`, yes, you can beat it.

Comment: Thank you. These are great references.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying question (challenge) is kind of silly. If the binary search answer is acceptable (where it sums sub arrays and sends them to IsEven) then I can think of a way to do it with E or less calls to IsEven (assuming the numbers are integers of course).

JavaScript to demonstrate

```
// sort the array by only the first bit of the number
A.sort(function(x,y) { return (x & 1) - (y & 1); });
// all of the evens will be at the beginning
for(var i=0; i < E && i < A.length; i++) {
    if(IsEven(A[i]))
        Print(A[i]);
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is what OP had in mind. If you did this, you could have simply used `A.filter(function(x) { return (x & 1) == 0); })` and argue that no calls to `IsEven` are needed at all.

Comment: @Groo - The subtle difference between "(x & 1) == 0" which is a synonym for IsEven and "(x & 1) - (y & 1)" which is a sorting comparison. The generally accepted answer with binary search uses an aggregate SUM (addition) operation on sub arrays, so I really can't presume what the OP had in mind or what would be allowed or not.

Comment: You are right, there are no "rules" in the question which would enforce one approach or the other. What I am trying to say is that, IMHO, "Is Even" is a special case of "Is Divisible By A Prime", and it's the only case where you can exploit computer's native numerical representation, and also the only one where there are only two classes of numbers (which allows sorting into two "bins").

Comment: This is why I would (personally) approach the problem as if the function was "IsMultipleOf13" or "IsMultipleOf39971" (source: [this](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt)), and that is why the answer from the initial post uses multiplication: because such function yields `true` for any product which contains at least one factor which is a multiple of the prime. The "sum" approach shown above is more of an attempt to show the expected algorithm complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution, but just few thoughts.

1. It is easy to see that if a solution exists for array length n that takes less than n tests, then for any array length m > n it is easy to see that there is always a solution with less than m tests. So, if you have a solution for n = 2 or 3 or 4, then the problem is solved.
2. You can split the array into pairs of numbers and for each pair: if the sum is odd, then exactly one of them is even, otherwise if one of the numbers is even, then both of them are even. This way for each pair it takes either one or two tests. Best case:n/2 tests, worse case:n tests, if even and odd numbers are chosen with equal probability, then: 3n/4 tests.

My hunch is there is no solution with less than n tests. Not sure how to prove it.

UPDATE: The second solution can be extended in the following way.

Check if the sum of two numbers is even. If odd, then exactly one of them is even. Otherwise label the set as "homogeneous set of size 2". Take two "homogenous set"s of same size n. Pick one number from each set and check if their sum is even. If it is even, combine these two sets to a "homogeneous set of size 2n". Otherwise, it implies that one of those sets purely consists of even numbers and the other one purely odd numbers.

Best case:n/2 tests. Average case: 3*n/2. Worst case is still n. Worst case exists only when all the numbers are even or all the numbers are odd.

Answer (score 0):

If we can add *and* multiply array elements, then we can compute every Boolean function (up to complementation) on the low-order bits. Simulate a circuit that encodes the positions of the even numbers as a number from 0 to nC0 + nC1 + ... + nCe - 1 represented in binary and use calls to `isEven` to read off the bits.

Number of calls used: within 1 of the **information-theoretic optimum**.

See also [fully homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption#Fully_homomorphic_encryption).